# Can function return without 'return' statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Without return statement any change inside a function should not be accessible right?(correct me if i am wrong) But this code gives output without a return statement

```
def my_fun(a):
    a[0] = 'new value:'     
    a[1] = a[1] + 1      

x = ['old value:', 99]
my_fun(x)
print (x[0], x[1])
```

i just ran this code and got out put as 
    new value: 100
i am using python 3.6. Also will this work in any other programming language?

Comment: My previous answer was woefully inaccurate, I've edited it since taking into account hiro protagonist's feedback.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, arguments are passed by reference, meaning that any modification made to them is retained after the call. However, reassigning an object changes the target of the reference, and any subsequent modifications cannot be retained.
Consider the following example:

```
def foo(bar):
    bar[0] = 2  # modification
    bar = []    # reassigment

x = [1]
print(x)
foo(x)
print(x)
```

This outputs:

> ```
> [1]
> [2]
> ```

Some objects, like tuples or integers, are immutable which means they can't be modified, and raise an exception when an attempt is made. They cannot be modified without being reassigned.

This is specific to Python. Java acts in a superficially similar fashion, but the implementation is very different: Objects are passed by reference and carry modifications over, whereas simple data types (`int`, `double`, `char`, etc.) are copied and modifications don't carry over. C and C++ never modify an object, the only way to retain modifications on an object is to pass a pointer on the object to the function.

Answer (score 1):

you pass a *mutable* argument `a` (or `x`) which is a `list` to your function. then you modify the lists contents. this will of course change your list `x`.

---

if you wanted to protect `x` from being modified you could define it as a tuple

```
x = ("old value:", 99)
```

calling `my_fun(x)` now would result in a `TypeError` (as the assignment will fail).

variables that are local to a function are not visible outside of the function.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the fact that an object is mutable is really relevant here, since an immutable object can't be modified outside of a function either. The behavior outlined by OP is specific to complex objects, and I think that's more relevant.

Comment: @Syncrossus i disagree. this *is* about mutability; in python there is no concept of *simple* vs *complex* objects (python has no 'atoms' - everything is a first class object). but mutability is a core concept... and it applies here.

Comment: @Syncrossus what you actually mean by *complex* objects in your answer are in fact *mutable* objects in python speak... or how do you make the distinction between complex and simple objects?

Comment: After having looked into it more, I realize you are right and this has to do with mutability, but the connection between mutability and functions isn't made clear in your answer. Modifications can only be carried over if they affect an attribute of a mutable object, whereas assignment rebinds the reference, which is why "simple types" like integers cannot have changes carried over: there is no way to change the value of an int without rebinding the reference. This emulates the behavior of Java, but is implemented very differently.

Comment: @Syncrossus yup. exactly. 'simple types' are immutable objects. (apart from that i am not claiming this is a good answer; but i don't think it deserves a downvote...)

Comment: To me, the distinction between complex and simple objects was that "simple" objects can only be changed by reassignment, like `int` and `float` whose attributes are not writable, whereas "complex" objects either have attributes which can be changed directly or or through methods. After reading up, I realize that while there is a functional difference between these types of objects, there is no real distinction between them on an implementation level.

Comment: sorry, i am a bit repetitive here, but what you are describing is *mutability* in python jargon...

Comment: You're right, it doesn't deserve a downvote. In my ignorance, I didn't see the connection between your answer and the question at hand. I also didn't know votes could be locked, and was expecting to be able to retract my downvote. I would undo it if I could. If you edit your answer, I'll be able to retract my downvote apparently.